# Problem with ring-method of du Nouy for calculating surface tension

Tags: surface-tension

I need to calculate the surface tension of a liquid with the ring-method of du Nouy and the correct formula to use is:

> $\gamma = \frac{F}{4\pi R}$

I understand that the surface tension is the force that acts on a certain length which, in this case, is the circumference of the ring. Since the circumference of the ring is $2\pi R$ where does this extra $\times2$ come from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at a cross section of the ring the geometry looks like:

[image: Ring]

Note that the ring raises a cylinder of the fluid with an inside and ouside surface, and both surfaces pull on the ring. The force from each surface is $\gamma 2\pi r$, so the total force is $\gamma 4\pi r$.

Comment: I see, though doesn't that mean the formula is slightly inaccurate since it assumes the inner circumference is the exact same as the outer circumference? Of course since a ring is being used this should be negligible, right?

Comment: @Joshua: The du Noüy ring method is not very accurate and it isn't used these days. The error from the difference in the inside and outside diameters isn't big compared to the errors inherent in the technique.