# Why is it tension in surface tension?

Tags: terminology, surface-tension

Why is it called surface tension not surface compression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason is that surface tension arises from attractive interactions between the molecules of a liquid A. In the bulk there are other molecules of liquid A all around so the interactions are balanced. At the interface however, there is a lack of molecules A on one side which results in a net force that pulls the surface molecules in the direction of the bulk. Since this is a pulling action of the liquid itself arising from the attractive forces (not a pushing action of the other liquid) it is termed a [tension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tension_%28physics%29).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [my answer to a related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92229/problem-with-ring-method-of-du-nouy-for-calculating-surface-tension/92235#92235). When using the du Noüy ring method for measuring surface tension the surface pulls on you rather than pushing. For more info have a look at the Wikipedia page describing [methods for measuring surface tension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensiometer_%28surface_tension%29). Note that the equipment is generically called a *tensiometer* because it works by measuring the pull the surface exerts.

As an analogy imagine holding a stretched rubber band. We say the rubber band is in tension because it exerts a pull on your hands not a push.