# What is meant by the word "length" in definition of surface tension?

Tags: forces, surface-tension

Surface tension is defined as the force applied per unit length. What is that "length" belonging to? I can imagine force being applied per area but not length.

"It would take a force of 72 dynes to break a surface film of water 1 cm long." Film is two dimensional. Isn't it?

My textbook didn't describe that what is that length of? I have surfed for it but didn't found what that word exactly mean there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image you have a U shaped piece of wire with a soap film inside it, and a straight piece of wire inside the U:

[image: Soap film]

The red line is the stright piece of wire that is free to move in the U - in effect a 2D version of a piston.

The surface tension of the soap film $\gamma$ pulls on the wire so it produces a force $F$ on it where $F$ is given by:

$$ F = 2\gamma \ell $$

with $\ell$ being the length of the wire (the factor of two is because a soap film has two surfaces and each surface pulls on the wire).

This is why the surface tension is a force per unit length. If you consider the force produced by the surface on some straight element then the force is the surface tension multiplied by the length over which the surface tension acts.

Comment: The two surfaces of soap film are those; one of which I can see in the image. Isn't so?

Comment: @SufyanNaeem: have a look at [my answer to this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92229/problem-with-ring-method-of-du-nouy-for-calculating-surface-tension). This explain where the factor of two comes from.